# Methods to validate whether user is logged in aren't working for Sinatra Application.

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have two helper methods below.

```
  helpers do
    def logged_in?
     !current_user.nil?
    end

  def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
```

I am using these methods to authenticate whether a user is logged in or if they need to log in or create an account. On my index page I have two routes that take me to either a log in page or a create user page. These routes are shown below.

**HTML View**

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Simple Meal Prep</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" 
    rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="landing_page_title">Welcome to Cookbook</h1>
 <h2 id="site_logline">A Simple App to keep track of your recipes</h2>
 <br></br>
 <a id="login_button" href="/login">Login</a>  <route 1>
 <br></br>
 <a id="signup_button" href="/signup">Sign Up</a> <route 2>
</body>
```

**Corresponding User Controller Routes**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

 get '/user_home' do
  if logged_in? then erb :"/users/user_home" else redirect '/' end
 end

 get '/login' do
  if logged_in? then redirect to '/user_home' else erb :"/users/login" 
   end
 end
end
```

The error that I am getting is when I click on my login button I get a sinatra error stating "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /login
Couldn't find User without an ID". Looking at the backtrace from sinatra I don't believe that my logged_in? method is working correctly. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what steps to take next or sees something that I'm not seeing. I can include any additional code or schema if needed. Thanks.

Comment: `session[:user_id]` is `nil` maybe try this `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

Comment: When are you setting `session[:user_id]`?

Comment: Use `find_by(id: session[:user_id])` .. `find_by` doesn't raise an error if the record is not found, it returns nil. `find` raises an error.

Comment: @maxpleaner 's suggestion is better use his. Also please do not use `if ... then ... else ... end` inline either put this over mutliple lines or use ternary `conditional ? true : false`

Comment: @maxpleaner, why not answer the question with your suggestion?  It's a concise solution, and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_by(id: session[:user_id])` instead of `find(session[:user_id])`.

`find` raises an error if a nil id is passed, or no matching record is found. `find_by` doesn't raise an error in either of these situations.

Since your code allows for the result of this query to be nil (the `@current_user` variable will be nil, and so will the return value of the `current_user` method) it seems this one change will solve your problem.